# SQL Server installation - SQL Server Management Studio is not to seen

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install SQL Server database and SQL Server Management Studio on my Windows 7 OS

After the installation, I don't see SQL Server Management Studio on my machine. Do I need to install SQL Server Management Studio separately?

[SQL server installation picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAUrf.png)

Comment: Yes, if you are install MS SQL 2017

Comment: 2016 as well i believe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of SQL Server 2016, the "SQL Server Management Studio" (SSMS) is a separate download. You can install SSMS 2016 and the new SSMS (current version, 17.4 I believe) side-by-side with older SSMS versions. But they are a separate download and must be installed separately. They are not "included" in the installer as an option like previous versions.

Here is a link: [Official Microsoft SSMS DownloadLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)